# Deciding an architecture for a titanium mobile application

Tags: javascript, database-design, architecture, titanium-mobile

I am fairly new to the development world. I need to built an app writing javascript on Titanium  that should run on iOS as well as Android using a single codebase. I am currently targeting iPhones at the moment. The app is about a shop that is into selling traditional clothes and letting interested people know about the collection that they have. Any idea about the architecture that i should decide. Since it is quite logical that the user will update his collection of clothing frequently how should i go about it? Should i give him the client application that will run on his pc that he will make use of to update his changes? Will Appstore accept such apps? Any other points i need to know as i need to start the development asap.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution will be an App with Web as backend. Means you can put the data in Web, and your app used particular URL's for fetching the required data in the form of XML and JSON.

Your app will parse the data and display it on the view.

If there is new images in the server, your app will download it to the iOS device.

---

Another option is an app which deals with HTML pages. Means you need to display the page on a web view. If you need to update the data, you can update it on the server. Also it can be of two type

1. Your app will load the page from remote server, using the url
2. Your app will download the page to iOS device and display it from there, until a new change occurs.

If you are interested in HTML and CSS, [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is another cross platform, that can also help you.

Comment: are you saying that i should be making a web app for the client if he wants to make changes and the ios app will then call the remote server to fetch data to get the updation the client had made using a url?

Comment: @adnanhussein: yes. If the admin need to change the data, he can change it on the server. Then all the installed application can re-fetch the new data from server.

Answer (score 0):

for rapid devlopment you can use python django...  in your case you can use Django-tastypie for backend will be good choice.since using django you can develop it in quick time and the tastypie has api services which can used easily for retrieval and sending data

you can go through this

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/